# How to get all parent categories of WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Get only all parent categories in WooCommerce without post id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use get_terms as :

```
$terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'product_cat','hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0]);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Finally some working and simple answer ...